# SPARQL simple query

Tags: sparql, ontology, owl

I have made an ontology for Email. I want to make a query to test but believe me I forgot to how to write a simple one!! can anyone help me? considering these :
Email has subject,sender,receiver,content 
I want to write sth like this : Select * from content where sender=Sanza,

how can I write it in SPARQL? may be : SELECT * ?Content WHERE ?Sender: Sanaz
can anyone re-write it?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

It should look to something like that:

```
SELECT ?content
WHERE {
  ?email  <http://www.example.org/sender>  "Sanza" .
  ?email <http://www.example.org/content>  ?content .
}
```

You can find more examples there: http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql_basic_patterns.html

Comment: the name of the property you are using in your ontology to store the reference to a sender.

Comment: indeed, it's the URI of the property "sender" in the ontology (with or without prefixes) ;-)